# Using ng-repeat on JSON containing JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm somewhat new to angular, and i'm having problems with my json and ng-repeats. I have a list of "modules" and then lists of "weeks" within them:

```
{
    "modules":
        {
            "module1":
                {
                   "title":"name of module1",
                   "description":"description of module1",
                   "weeks":{"week1":{"title":"Week 01"}
                },
            "module2":
                {
                   "title":"name of module2",
                   "description":"description of module2",
                   "weeks":{"week2":{"title":"Week 02"},"week3":{"title":"Week 03"}
                }
        }
}
```

my final output is a table, and I can get the modules to repeat, but I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong by getting the weeks to loop. Here is my template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules">
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 class="moduletitle">{{ module.title }}</h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <p>{{ module.description }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="week in ocw.modules.weeks">
    <td>
        {{ week.title }}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So that will output 2 tables, with the proper titles and descriptions, but I can't seem to get the weeks to display correctly. Note that some "modules" have more that one "week". I'm not really sure if the error is in my template or json.

Thanks for any help. 
S

Comment: pls share your fiddle as object structure seems to have syntax error

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would change your data structure so your modules and weeks are an array of objects.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/e41n9vAMMLf0WWIUQ8HO?p=preview

json data:

```
{
    "modules":
        [
                {
                   "title":"name of module1",
                   "description":"description of module1",
                   "weeks":[{"id":1, "title":"Week 01"}]
                },

                {
                   "title":"name of module2",
                   "description":"description of module2",
                   "weeks":[{"id":2, "title":"Week 02"},{"id":3,"title":"Week 03"}]
                }
        ]
}
```

And then your markup would be:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules">
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 class="moduletitle">{{ module.title }}</h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <p>{{ module.description }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="week in module.weeks">
    <td>
        {{ week.title }}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you are iterating over each module which in this case is `module` to get the weeks it is just `module.weeks` much the same as `module.title`.  In your example you are inside the iteration and trying to reference `ocw.modules.weeks` which doesn't match your json structure.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. It's much cleaner and less confusing. Thanks so much!

Comment: @lucuma Finally I found a good example on how to properly output nested json with Angularjs. Thanks +1

Comment: What about if I have a `key` that has a `space` in it?

Comment: @LekzFlores In javascript you can do `obj["key with space"]`

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in ocw.modules.weeks">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in module.weeks">
```

because you now have a module in your scope, and it's that module's weeks you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, if your table has some style and `thead`, this `ngRepeat` will create multiple tables, which is not what we want.

To avoid this, just use the first `ng-repeat` in a `tbody` element:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3 class="moduletitle">{{ module.title }}</h3>
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <p>{{ module.description }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="week in module.weeks">
            <td>{{ week.title }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```