# How to frame a angularjs html format with the multi child object values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My Data (array of objects):

```
$scope.names = [{ "name": "John", "imgsrc": "Smith", "navPath": true, "subValues": [{ "subName": "home" }, {"subName": "home"}]},
{ "name": "Hege", "imgsrc": "Hege1", "navPath": true, "subValues": [{ "subName": "Hege11" }]},
{ "name": "Kai", "imgsrc": "Kai1", "navPath": true, "subValues": [{ "subName": "Kai11" },{"subName": "Kai12"},{"subName": "Kai13"}]}];
```

My Expected OUTPUT HTML:

```
<div>
    <a src="Smith.html">John</a>
    <div>
        <span>home</span>
        <span>home</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a src="Hege1.html">Hege</a>
    <div>
        <span>Hege11</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a src="Kai1.html">Kai</a>
    <div>
        <span>Kai11</span>
        <span>Kai12</span>
        <span>Kai13</span>
    </div>
</div>.
```

What is the exact coding format in AngularJS to get this OUTPUT?. I am New to AngularJS, so those who try to explain please provide me to clear understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code you attempted? We aren't here to do your work for you and write code for you from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to show each element of a list in AngularJS. The object you get for each item in the list is a normal JavaScript object, so you can get fields and call methods on them. You can even use an ngRepeat instead another ngRepeat.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the solution from this stackoverflow.
[Using ng-repeat on JSON containing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485274/using-ng-repeat-on-json-containing-json)

Json data:

```
{
    "modules":
        [
                {
                   "title":"name of module1",
                   "description":"description of module1",
                   "weeks":[{"id":1, "title":"Week 01"}]
                },

                {
                   "title":"name of module2",
                   "description":"description of module2",
                   "weeks":[{"id":2, "title":"Week 02"},{"id":3,"title":"Week 03"}]
                }
        ]
}
```

And then your markup would be:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules">
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 class="moduletitle">{{ module.title }}</h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <p>{{ module.description }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="week in module.weeks">
    <td>
        {{ week.title }}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```