# How to display nested JSON elements in HTML table with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following JSON with nested elements

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "gender": "m",
        "places": [{
            "name": "London",
            "contacts": [{
                "type": "phone",
                "value": "123456789"
            },{
                "type": "email",
                "value": "johnsmith@example.com"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Paris",
            "contact": [{
                "type": "phone",
                "value": "987654321"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "gender": "f",
        "places": [{
            "name": "Paris",
            "contacts": [{
                "type": "email",
                "value": "janedoe@example.com"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

and I'm trying to display it in HTML table with AngularJS and ng-repeat as follows:

```
Name            Places      Email               Telephone
---------------------------------------------------------
Jonh Smith      London      smith@example.com   123456789
                Paris                           987654321
Jane Doe        Paris       doe@example.com
```

Is there a nice way to do it (in one stroke - without too many nested loops) or should I really loop contacts over and over in each "td"-element?

EDIT: I'm looking for an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485274/using-ng-repeat-on-json-containing-json) one here, the only "solution" (if i even can call it that) I came up with is to iterate locations in each "table data"-element over and over, so if each person has 3 locations with 4 phone/emails there will be like 12 iterations per cell or 48 iterations per person (row).

Is there really no smart way to do it in ng-repeat or should I just give up with table layout by nested JSON?

Comment: You could do an ng-bind to the td's that you want the values in and give it a function. That function would take the array of data you want to display, pull the data out of it and return it as a string. Keeps your HTML template clean.

Answer (score 2):

To give an example based on my comment to your question: use an ng-bind-html on each of the td's and use a function for it that receives the {object}.places array. (In my html I named it person), then in that function get the data you want out of the array and return it as a string

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "gender": "m",
      "places": [{
          "name": "London",
          "contacts": [{
              "type": "phone",
              "value": "123456789"
          },{
              "type": "email",
              "value": "johnsmith@example.com"
          }]
        },{
          "name": "Paris",
          "contacts": [{
              "type": "phone",
              "value": "987654321"
          }]
        }]
    },{
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "gender": "f",
      "places": [{
        "name": "Paris",
        "contacts": [{
            "type": "email",
            "value": "janedoe@example.com"
        }]
      }]
    }];
    
    $scope.getPlaces = function(places) {
      var cities = '';
      for (var i = places.length; i-- > 0;) {
        cities += places[i].name + '<br />';
      }
      console.log(cities);
      return cities;
    }

    $scope.getEmails = function(places) {
      var emails = '';
      for (var i = places.length; i-- > 0;) {
        for (var j = places[i].contacts.length; j-- > 0;) {
          if (places[i].contacts[j].type === 'email') {
            emails += places[i].contacts[j].value + '<br />'
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(emails);
      return emails;
    }

    $scope.getPhones = function(places) {
      var phones = '';
      for (var i = places.length; i-- > 0;) {
        for (var j = places[i].contacts.length; j-- > 0;) {
          if (places[i].contacts[j].type === 'phone') {
            phones += places[i].contacts[j].value + '<br />'
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(phones);
      return phones; 
    }    
}]);
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cities</th>
      <th>Emails</th>
      <th>Phones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <td ng-bind="person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName">
      <td ng-bind-html="getPlaces(person.places)">
      <td ng-bind-html="getEmails(person.places)">
      <td ng-bind-html="getPhones(person.places)">
    </tr>    
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

That should give you a good idea of where to start. Also, note that it requires ngSanitize so make sure you include that if you wind up using this method.