# AngularJS access JSON index values dynamically

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My scope data:

```
$scope.data = 
 "category": [{
"name": "cat1",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "define",
    "count": 6
}]
}, {
"name": "cat2",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "type",
    "count": 6
}]
}, {
"name": "Company",
"behaviour": "multi-select",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "VW",
    "count": 4
}, {
    "label": "Renault",
    "count": 1
}, {
    "label": "Fiat",
    "count": 1
}]
}, {
"name": "Make",
"behaviour": "multi-select",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "Gold",
    "count": 3
}]
}, {
"name": "Color",
"behaviour": "normal",
"selected": 0,
"values": [{
    "label": "White",
    "count": 3
}, {
    "label": "Blue",
    "count": 2
}, {
    "label": "Green",
    "count": 1
}]
}]
```

How can I access the "name":"value" without using indexes? as the data might grow and change and I don't want to assign an index value anywhere? I'd still want to filter such as:

```
| {name: 'Make'}: true)
```

in my mark up to show

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ng-repeat on JSON containing JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485274/using-ng-repeat-on-json-containing-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the json is incorrect, i corrected it (next time you can use this site to see if your json is valid [JSONVALIDATOR](http://jsonlint.com/)) 
 If you want to access at value of the name do this

In your controller :

```
$scope.data = [
{
    "name": "cat1",
    "behaviour": "normal",
    "selected": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "define",
            "count": 6
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "cat2",
    "behaviour": "normal",
    "selected": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "type",
            "count": 6
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Company",
    "behaviour": "multi-select",
    "selected": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "VW",
            "count": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Renault",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "label": "Fiat",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Make",
    "behaviour": "multi-select",
    "selected": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "Gold",
            "count": 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Color",
    "behaviour": "normal",
    "selected": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "White",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "label": "Blue",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "label": "Green",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
];
```

In your HTML

```
      <div ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d.name}} </div>
```

If you want to display values of the object with the name 'Company' you can do this like in my working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyGjN) :

Just add a new ng-repeat :

```
   <div ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d.name}} 
         <div ng-if="d.name == 'Company'" ng-repeat="da in d.values">{{da.label}}</div>      
  </div>
```

Comment: I need to be able to specify however that  name=Company for example

Comment: If this is Company you do something different? Is it that you mean?

Comment: So no, I would do for example:

<div ng-repeat="d in data | {name: 'Company'}: true)">

and show a count so value for example

Comment: Codepen added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

First off, the format of your data is not correct JSON format, run it through an online validator.

To access the element, you would simply be able to through:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{ item.name }} {{ item.behaviour }} etc...
</li>
```

Get rid of category within $scope.data... just let it be an array like a typical JSON value.

Comment: @carton - ha, must have posted at the same time.. Simple enough issue

Comment: I can't play about with the structure :)