# How to force an expression passed from JSON into Angular scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I'm looking for best practices direction on how take HTML that comes from JSON and trigger a modal/toggle when clicked.

The JSON has 100 entries, about 10 contain links that will trigger a pop-up. They appear in the text as 'Schedule #' (where # is A - G).

My first approach is to simply write the Angular mark-up into the JSON, and have it rendered into the scope:

In from JSON:

```
"Are the details defined in 
<a href='/#/' class='schedule' 
   data-ng-click='modal.active = modal.active === true ? false : true'>
      Schedule G
</a>?"
```

Obviously - this isn't working because angular doesn't know about the ng-click OR the modal. $sce is doing it's job for trustAsHTML - but, nothing I can find will recognize the expression.

Am I on the right path?

I've been poking through $apply, $compile, and $parse documentation - but none of it seems to like what I'm doing.

Alternatively, would it be better to regex for the 'Schedule', and then build the angular expression into it programatically? I'm coming up empty on how to approach this task.

Comment: If you were to put angular syntax in the JSON, $compile is the right path, although that's an ugly solution. You should instead just parse the JSON out as part of an ng-repeat, placing the elements as needed in your html. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485274/using-ng-repeat-on-json-containing-json

Comment: can you provide your code here?

Comment: @JamesGentes Thanks for this. I'm using the ng-repeat for the overall model, but, this one child object has a link mid-sentence which needs to read existing $scope. Can you explain why it's an ugly solution - other than, it FEELS ugly? Which it does. How would I use ng-repeat in this way?

Comment: ah, then you're probably stuck using $compile. There's nothing wrong with that approach, it's just not the simplest solution, but you might be stuck in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<p data-ng-bind-html="__services.trustAsHTML(__data.steps[step.text])" data-angular-compile></p>
```

COMPILE DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('app.directives.AngularCompile', [], ["$compileProvider", function($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.directive('angularCompile', ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.angularCompile);
            },
            function(value) {
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
}]);
```

The JSON object has HTML links with `ng-click` attributes, employs `ng-bind-html`, with `$sce`'s `trustAsHtml` to make the HTML safe. I have also used a custom angular-compile directive to compile the angular click listener into the app after the json is loaded in a `$q` promise.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not completely solved this problem, I do know that the answer to the question about direction is solidly $compile. I found [this great blog post](http://brilliantbritz.com/2014/03/18/compiling-html-on-the-fly-via-compileprovider-directive/) about it, which was inspired by a similar StackOverflow question... referenced within the post.